# Iconize Xamarin with Fontawesome

Tags: android, xamarin, plugins, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm trying to use the [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize) NuGet package for Xamarin, but I'm not having much luck. At the moment I'm working with a simple Android app. I've installed Iconize per the instructions and, save for an error on the line:

```
FormsPlugin.Iconize.Droid.IconControls.Init(Resource.Id.toolbar, Resource.Id.tabs);
```

(the compiler didn't like the Resource.Id.toolbar or Resource.Id.tabs so I removed it) everything compiles and runs. However, when I try to add an IconButton with a Fontawesome image, I get `"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` error that points back to 
the line `LoadApplication( new App() );` in the MainActivity.cs.

I'm trying to add the IconButton to a grid in code (not XAML) using

```
        grid.Children.Add( new IconButton
        {
            Image = "fa-info-circle"
        }, 3, 2 );
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? The examples on the Iconize page haven't been very useful and I haven't found any examples on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally found something that was useful. I found a clue on [this page](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/04/17/how-to-create-a-nice-rouded-icon/) and some other information on the project [issues](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/issues/1) page on Github.

Ultimately, to get the icon to display I used

```
        grid.Children.Add( new IconButton
        {
            Text = "fa-info-circle",
        }, 3, 2 );
```

It was the Text property and not the Image property that I should have used.

Hope this helpful to someone else.